# Open an OS X app on Lion/ML from another Cocoa process without restoring windows

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm looking to replicate the behavior of the "open" command's "--fresh" option in a Cocoa app. This option "Launches the app fresh, that is, without restoring windows."

I've whipped up an example app which launches Xcode, but haven't figured out which API exposes this control.

```
NSURL *executableURL = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.dt.Xcode"];
NSError *error = nil;
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:executableURL
                                              options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault
                                        configuration:nil
                                                error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error launching Xcode: %@", error);
}
```

Looking at the list of NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions, I don't see anything that hints at affecting state restoration. There are only a few configuration options available, such as passing arguments, modifying the environment or passing an Apple event to the launched app.

Can the state restoration be prevented using an Apple event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application state is stored in ~/Library/Saved Application State. Xcodes state is in a subfolder named com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState. One option is to rename this folder before launch, then rename it back. Might be a better way via argument, but I don't think there is a universal argument for it.